# How to get average time difference interval in a group?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put together a PHP MySQL query using my transaction table:

```
transaction_id customer_id transaction_order_date
--------------  -----------  ---------------------- 
1001            1            2014-05-01 10:00:00 
1002            1            2014-05-01 11:00:00  
1003            2            2014-05-02 10:00:00 
1004            2            2014-05-03 10:00:00 
1005            1            2014-05-03 10:00:00`
```

And I want the result like this:

```
customer_id 1 
avg_time_trans 18920(in second)
customer_id 2 
avg_time_trans 12220(in second)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Can you explain how you got your expected results? I'm not sure what you're actually looking for. I can't find a relationship in your table that gives those results.

Comment: I want to know the interval avg time of my transaction per user_id
like user_id 1 avg of his transaction is 6 hours (it's ok if it in second coz i can convert it in hours myself)..
(such 4 transaction in 24 hours)
i'd have to try function like timediff when I used to find the avg time of transaction_order_date to transaction_confirmation_date >> AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(transaction_confirmation_date,transaction_order_date))) AS timediff